# error in compiling using cmake utility

Tags: c++, gcc, xerces, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile my gcc code using the following make command .
OS :Redhat  ,gcc - 4.1
But I am getting error as follows :
rmtrain@lintrni130 $ /usr/local/bin/make all

```
[ 21%] Built target GCVCore
Linking CXX executable CFE
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libicui18n.so.36, needed by ../../Generic/icu/lib/libicuio.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libxalanMsg.so.110, needed by ../../Generic/Xalan/lib/libxalan-c.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
CMakeFiles/CFE.dir/trnuser1/rmtrain/DevelopmentEnv/Generic/ConvUI/GCVConvUISetting.o: In function `xercesc_2_6::XMLAttDefList::~XMLAttDefList()':
GCVConvUISetting.cpp:(.text._ZN11xercesc_2_613XMLAttDefListD0Ev[xercesc_2_6::XMLAttDefList::~XMLAttDefList()]+0x2f): undefined reference to `xercesc_2_6::XMemory::operator delete(void*)'
```

Please Help with this .

Comment: Completely unrelated to the problem, but you *might* want to consider updating... the version numbers you gave give me the creeps. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i reinstalled icu 3.2 instead of 3.6.It worked fine then.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings means that some libraries you link to have dependencies on other shared libraries, and those libraries weren't found in the linker's search path.  The linker manual describes how it forms that search path in the [docs for the  `-rpath-link` option](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-link_002dtime-runtime-library-search-path-219)

They're only warnings, so haven't caused your link to fail. It will be a problem if those required libs aren't found at run-time, but is not necessarily a problem at link-time.

If you want to silence the warnings you will need to find out which directory contains `libicui18n.so.36` and `libxalanMsg.so.110` and use one of the methods described in the manual to tell the linker to look in that directory.

The last line is the real problem, and indicates you are not linking to the library which defines that symbol. You'll need to find out which library it is and link to it with `-lfoo`, it will probably be something like `-lxerces`

Comment: I am using Cmake(2.8) utility to compile the code.How Do i link to the correct library using cmake utility?

Comment: I don't use cmake so I don't know, maybe try reading some documentation.

Comment: the -rpath-link option was correct for removing the warning though using cmake utility the implementation was different.